# Why would there be an ifconfig listing en2 with 169.254.x.x on OSX 10.6.8?

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard

Web browsing was becoming very slow, after trying in two different places (home,starbucks).
I was looking at ifconfig output and everything I found reasons for, lo0 gif0 stf0, except for one of the enX interfaces:

```
en2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 0b:0b:0b:0b:0b:0b 
inet6 fe80::223:32ff:fec7:d2dc%en2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
inet 169.254.193.122 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
media: autoselect (10baseT/UTP <full-duplex>)
status: active
```

I used sudo ifconfig en2 down, and the browsing immediately improved.
I am wondering what this is/was?

Comment: `169.254.0.0/24` is a link local address that gets used when there is nothing connected on that network, or there is no DHCP server offering addresses.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

Comment: @Zoredache is right about the 169.254.x.y address.  en2 is your ethernet port, and with nothing connected, it shouldn't affect anything.  Considering how often I used my ethernet connection, I usually just disabled it entirely. Really shouldn't cause any issues, but perhaps something had bound to it and was waiting for replies.  Nice that 'down'ing the interface helped.